# How to add authors contact info to author metabox in post editor?

Tags: author, post-editor

By default the Author Metabox on the post editor displays only a drop down to set the author of that respective post/page. I'd like the author's contact info (email address) displayed on the Author metabox as well (only in the post/page editor, not on the front-end). Currently I have to go to my Users and search for the author of the post to view their contact info, which isn't very efficient.

Is there a tutorial or snippet to achieve this? I have not been able to find anything thus far. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Modifying the core meta box may be more difficult than it sounds, and is a non-trivial request. It may be possible to change the labels of the authors in the dropdown box, which would be less work but still non-trivial. Have you considered adding an additional column to the posts list showing the users email? Have you considered the legal/privacy implications of freely sharing that email address in the admin area to anybody who can edit posts?

Comment: Thanks Tom. I had not considered adding a column to the posts list to display the user (authors) email. I will need to research how to make that kind of change, as I'm a novice at coding.
Regarding the privacy implications, that won't be an issue for us as only our staff has access to the admin, but I do appreciate you bringing that up, as that'd definitely be a concern for a site that gave users access to the back-end.

Comment: You could always ask it as a question =)

Comment: Thanks, just posted it: [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158706/how-to-add-authors-email-to-posts-and-custom-post-types-admin-screen).