# Adding an email column to a Custom Post Types Admin Screen?

Tags: customization, admin, columns

I am trying to add a column to my Custom Post Type Admin Screen that will show the author's email address. Any advice for novice coders (such as myself) that describe how to accomplish this? I've come up empty in searching for a tutorial specific to what I'm trying to do.

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: The codex has some good info on that: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_edit-post_type_columns

Comment: This question was a follow on from another question, +1 for expanding on a question

Comment: Here´s a [tutorial](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/12/05/modifying-admin-post-lists-in-wordpress/) I've used it before, along with the link daniel shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try this:

```
add_filter('manage_edit-movie_columns', 'custom_add_new_columns');
function custom_add_new_columns( $columns ){
    $columns['author_email'] = 'Email';
    return $columns;
}
add_action('manage_movie_posts_custom_column', 'custom_manage_new_columns', 10, 2);
function custom_manage_new_columns( $column_name, $id ){
    if ('author_email'==$column_name){
     $current_item = get_post($id);
     $author_id = $current_item->post_author;
     $author_email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author_id);
     echo '<a href="mailto:'.$author_email.'">'.$author_email.'</a>';
    }
}
```

Here, I have used custom post type `movie`. You need to replace movie word in hooks with your custom post type name.

For example, if your CPT is `flower`, hooks should be `manage_edit-flower_columns` and `manage_flower_posts_custom_column`.

First function adds heading of columns in the table. Second function adds content of the column according to the current post.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for.